# Next.js does not render authentication state properly after keycloak login

Tags: next.js, keycloak, server-side-rendering

I have a basic next.js application that does two things:

1. provide an authentication mechanism using keycloak
2. talk to a backend server that authorizes each request using the keycloak-access-token

I use the `@react-keycloak/ssr` library to achieve this. The problem now is that after I login and get redirected back to my application the cookie that contains the kcToken is empty. After I refresh my page it works like expected.

I understand that maybe my entire process flow is wrong. If so, what is the "usual" way to achieve what is mentioned above?

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const base64KcToken = context.req.cookies.kcToken // the cookie that keycloak places after login
    const kcToken = base64KcToken ? Buffer.from(base64KcToken, "base64") : ""

    // the backend server passes the token along to keycloak for role-based authorization
    const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/info`, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + kcToken 
            }
        })

    const data = await res.json()

    // ... exception handling is left out for readability ...

    return {
        props: {
            data
        }
    }
}

export default function Home({data}) {
    const router = useRouter() // the next.js client side router to redirect to keycloak
    const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak() // keycloak instance configured in _app.js
    if (keycloak && !initialized && keycloak.createLoginUrl) router.push(keycloak.createLoginUrl())
    return (
        <div> ... some jsx that displays data ... </div>
   )
}
```

This process basically works but it feels really bad because a user that gets redirected after login is not able to see the fetched data unless he refreshes the entire page. This is because when getServerSideProps() is called right after redirect the base64KcToken is not there yet.

Also everything related to the login-status (eg. logout button) only gets displayed after ~1sec, when the cookie is loaded by the react-keycloak library.

Comment: What exactly happens when getting redirected after login? Could you share that code? And why wouldn't the cookie be already set?

Comment: basically i see the page without the server data (because the cookie is empty). what code do you mean? I dont have more next.js code.

Comment: How do you login?

Comment: This is done by the line `    if (keycloak && !initialized && keycloak.createLoginUrl) router.push(keycloak.createLoginUrl())` this redirects the user to the keycloak login page where you enter your information and after a successful login you get redirected back to your application and keycloak sets your access token in a cookie

Comment: So i did not find an answer to my question so far. It looks more complicated than I thought in the beginning. Basically a simple workaround is to not use server-side authentication at all in next.js with keycloak. I will dig more into it. there is a keycloak-nodejs-adapter but it expects different request / response objects so it does not work so far.

Comment: @JonathanR did you find any solution? We are stuck in the same situation. I also tried to use keycloak nodejs adapter or next-auth lib (it did't work so badly, but i couldn't solve some cases).

Comment: Unfortunately only a work around but actually one that other pages use as well as I learned (I think youtube did it a while back). Before the token call is not through, I hide the page completely and only when the call is through do I render it's content. This makes loading time "longer" but at least there is no false information shown